# Let A be an $n\times n$ real matrix. Then is it true that every eigenvalue of $A^tA$ is a non negative real number?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an $n\times n$ real matrix. Then is it true that every eigenvalue of $A^tA$ is a non negative real number?

I know $(A^tA)^t=A^tA$ so we can conclude that $A^tA$ is symmetric matrix. Since it is a symmetric matrix, all its eigenvalues are real.

But I am not able to see why it should be a non negative real number.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^tAx= \lambda x$ and let us denote the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^n$ by $(\cdot, \cdot).$

Then $\lambda (x,x)=(A^tAx,x)=(Ax,Ax).$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

$ \langle A^{T}Ax, x \rangle=\langle Ax, Ay \rangle=\|Ax\|^{2} \geq 0$ for all $x$. If $x$ is an eigen vector with eigen value $\lambda$ this gives $\lambda \|x\|^{2} \geq 0$ fo $\lambda \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^tA$ is not only symmetric, it is also positive semi-definite. In other words, for any vector $v$ we have

$v^t(A^tA)v = u^tu =|u|^2 \ge 0$

where $Av=u$. So if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^tA$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have

$v^t(A^tA)v \ge 0\\ \Rightarrow v^t(\lambda v) \ge 0 \\ \Rightarrow \lambda |v|^2 \ge 0$

What does this tell you about $\lambda$ ?